# Removing tabs from tabhost causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I need to be able to close tabs in a TabHost for an android app I'm working on. I am currently calling this code.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeViewAt(toDelete);
```

Where toDelete is the index of the tab that called the removal method. It looks like that code removes the tab, from the split second I can see it before it crashes. I'm thinking there's another removal method I need to call somewhere, because it appears to crash when attempting to draw the tab that was removed. I also tried

```
tabHost.removeViewAt(toDelete);
```

But it crashed because it didn't have a view at toDelete, which is expected since (I think) it just contains the tab widget rather than the actual tabs.

Here are my crash logs

```
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:323)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-04 16:05:53.149: E/AndroidRuntime(7885):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas on what other methods I should be calling? Or am I going down the entirely wrong path?

Edit: I just tried opening 5 tabs and closing the second one. It didn't crash at first, but it did have some VERY odd behavior. When I click on a tab, it shows the next one to the right as being highlighted, but displays the correct tab, until I click the last tab at which point the app crashes. A few screen shots in case it helps to describe my issue.

When I click the songs tab before closing a tab
[image: Displays songs in song tab]

When I click the tab for a specific song before closing a tab
[image: Displays song lyrics in correct tab]

When I click the songs tab after closing the current program tab. The correct contents are displayed but the wrong tab looks selected.
[image: After clicking the songs tab after closing current program tab]

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `tabs.getTabWidget().removeView`, you need show another tab, `tabs.setCurrentTab(0)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index));
```

I remove it by this method , you can try it with the method